# Proof that any number can be represented as the sum of two relatively prime numbers that are each multiplies by some integer.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question that I am being asked is as follows:
"Prove that for every pair of positive integer p and q that have no prime factors in common, and every other positive integer r, there are integers m and n such that mp + nq = r."

This is not a homework or test question, it is a review question that I am stuck on.

I have gathered that I am supposed to apply the prime factorization theorem and the quotient-remainder theorem in some way, but I am completely stumped. I have gotten no farther than stating the premise and what it means mathematically to be relatively prime numbers. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you first show that there exist $m,n$ for which $mp+nq=1$?

Comment: Do you know the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: ... or Bézout's identity?

Answer (score 3):

This is an extension of [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity).  Assuming that:

We have $\gcd (p,q) = 1$.  By Bezout's identity, there are integers $m,n$ such that $mp + nq = 1$.  Then \begin{align*}
    r(mp + nq) &= r(1)  \\
    rmp + rnq  &= r  \\
    (rm)p + (rn)q &= r  \text{,}
\end{align*}
so $rm$ and $rn$ are such a pair of numbers.

Say we don't have Bezout's identity.  How would we obtain it?  We would use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find $m$ and $n$.