# If $\gcd(a,x)=1$, then $a\mathbb N+b, x\mathbb N+y$ intersects.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have tried to think as intersections of two lines but for $2x+3$ and $5x+7$ is failed to have integer intersections (but not sure it is enough counterexample).

Is the above generalisation correct? Can you give a counter-example, or a hint for how to prove it?

Comment: you have $ 2 * 2 + 3 = 5 * 0 + 7$. The "x" need not be the same.

Comment: You assumed slightly too much. It's not that $2x+3 = 5x+7$ but rather that $2x+3 = 5y+7$ for some natural numbers $x,y$.

Comment: Immediate consequence of CRT, e.g. apply the Theorem in the dupe to $\,z\equiv b\pmod{a},\ z\equiv y\pmod{x}\ \ $

Comment: "Immediate consequence of CRT"  *minor* additional step.  CRT says $w\equiv b\pmod a; w\equiv y\pmod x$ has unique solutions $\pmod {ax}$ so there exist *integers* $M,N$ so that $w = aM + b=xN + y$.  But it doesn't say $M,N$ are natural numbers.  But that is an exceedingly *minor* point. ..... $w+k(ax) = a(M+kx) =x(N+ka)$ so we can add multiples of $x$ and $a$ to $M,N$ until they are both positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking in terms of straight lines and looking for points of intersection where both lines have the same output *for the same input* is not the best analogy.  It's better to think of these as unstructured unordered *sets* which are like bags of groceries that they have a bunch of stuff dumped in them in no particular order and an "intersection" simply means the two bags both have the same item somewhere. ("*You* bought mushrooms and tampons too!  So did I!")

$2\mathbb N + 3 = \{5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29......\}$ and $5\mathbb N + 7= \{12,17,22,27,32,....\}$

Notice they both have $17$ and $27$ and $37$ etc in them.  Note those numbers aren't in both for the same *reason*... If $17 \in 2\mathbb N+3 = \{2\color{blue}n + 3|\color{blue}nn\in \mathbb N\}$ it is because if $\color{blue}{n= 7}$ we get $2\cdot\color{blue}{7} +3=17$ which $17 \in 5\mathbb N + 7=\{5\color{red}n + 7|\color{red}n \in \mathbb N\}$ because if $\color{red}n = 2$ we get $5\cdot\color{red}2+7=17$... but we don't care *why* the items are in the bag, just that they are both in each of the bags.

("I bought the mushrooms as the fifth item right after the milk and a picked up the tampons at the check out counter as my last item"  "Oh, not me.  I went shopping just because I needed tampons so I bought the first thing.  Then I thought about dinner so I bought pasta, mushrooms, and onions.  Mushrooms were the third thing I bought.")

..........

So this is actually much looser.

You mus show that there exist natural number $M,K$ so that $aM + b= xK +y$ where $M,K$ can be *any* natural numbers and need not have any thing in common.

That would mean $aM - xK = (y-b)$.  By Bezout's lemma you know we can find integers$M', K'$ so that $aM' + xK' = 1$ so if we let $M = (y-b)M'$ and $K = -(y-b)K'$ we get $aM - xK = y-b$.

Or only concern is whether or not $M,K$ are both positive.  I'll let you work the details.

(Note: if $a,b \ge 0$ then $aM' + bK' = 1$ would mean only one of $M'$ or $K'$ is positive and the other is either negative or $0$.)

=====

Postsript:  For the record the two sets $a\mathbb N + b$ and $x \mathbb N + y$ don't just intersect and have *one* item in common.  They have an infinite number of items in common.

.....

Notice that every $10K + 7 = 2(5K + 2) + 3= 5(2K) + 7 \in (2\mathbb N + 3)\cap( 5\mathbb N + 7)$.  So for all $K$ we have $10K + 7$ is in the intersection.

That may give you a hint to a more direct way (but not necessarily easier) way to solve it than my Bezout solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is true, and in fact you only need the first condition $\gcd(a,x)=1$. This follows from the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). For example, $2\mathbb N+3$ and $5\mathbb N+7$ both include all points in $10\mathbb N+7$.

Comment: is lcm, always works?

Comment: what is the general form of $a\mathbb N+b\cap x\mathbb N+y$ if $(a,x)=1$

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale it will be $ax\mathbb N+c$ for some value of $c$. Assuming your definition of $\mathbb N$ includes $0$, there will always be a unique common point in $[\max(b,y),ax+\max(b,y))$ which will be the value of $c$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Find integers $A, X$ such that $ a  A +xX = y - b$.

Comment: To show $A$, $X$ exist: $gcd(x,a) = 1$, then $\alpha x+\beta a = 1$, for some $\alpha, \beta$ .Then multiply both sides by $(y-b)$.

Answer (score 0):

First since $gcd(x,a)=1$, there exist $\alpha$, $\beta$, such that
([Bézout's identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056267/proof-that-any-number-can-be-represented-as-the-sum-of-two-relatively-prime-numb))$$\alpha x - \beta a = 1$$ Now multiply both sides by $k = b-y$.

$$(k \alpha ) x - (k \beta)a = b-y$$
$$(k \alpha ) x + y = (k \beta)a +b$$